# Stat, Blocks and Sector size - ext4

Tags: filesystems, stat

While reading upon how files are stored in the filesystem, I created a testfile which happened to be of size 217 bytes. Checking the output of `stat` on this file, I saw that this file is occupying 8 blocks. Initially I thought that there is no way that a file of size 217 bytes can be using 8 blocks when the Block size is 4096 bytes and the value at `Blocks:` should be `1` instead of `8`. Then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346807/how-does-stat-command-calculate-the-blocks-of-a-file), [this](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_stat.htm) and [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and realized that the `Blocks:` value is the number of 512 bytes space occupied by the file. And since the minimum size of a block is 4096 bytes, even a file of size 2 bytes will occupy 8 blocks (because 4096/512 = 8).

```
[root@server ~]# stat smallfile.txt
  File: `smallfile.txt'
  Size: 217             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

I had read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector) that:

> "Each sector stores a fixed amount of user-accessible data,
>   traditionally 512 bytes for hard disk drives (HDDs) and 2048 bytes for
>   CD-ROMs and DVD-ROMs. Newer HDDs use 4096-byte (4 KiB) sectors, which
>   are known as the Advanced Format (AF)."

All of the systems I have access to used HDDs with sector size 512 bytes. So I believe that the `st_blocks` (as explained the 2nd and 3rd hyperlinks I have given) matches the sector size of the hard-drive? So the question is:

- In future, if I am to have the same 217 bytes sized file on an HDD with a sector size of 4096 bytes, would the `stat` command on the file would show `Blocks: 1` instead of `Blocks: 8` (since 4096/4096 = 1) ?
- Or `st_blocks` will always use 512 byte as the single minimum unit regardless of the sector size?
- Or has it something to do with the VFS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The links you give explicitly state:

> The st_blocks field indicates the number of blocks allocated to the file, 512-byte units.

So they're always in units of 512-byte blocks, regardless of what underlying device is used. The `stat` command simply displays what the `stat` system call returns. The 512-byte block is a historic thing, defined in POSIX. Compare for example these:

```
$ ls -s smallfile.txt
4 smallfile.txt
$ env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ls -s smallfile.txt
8 smallfile.txt
```

GNU `ls` displays blocks by default in 1kB blocks, but when forced to comply with POSIX it shows 512-byte blocks.

Comment: That answers my question. I had wondered whether its 512 bytes is historic.